# Breakdown voltage avalanche photodiodes

Tags: semiconductor-physics, electronics

What is the best definition to obtain the breakdown voltage of an avalanche photodiode?

Update: Is it even possible to determine it graphically? E.g. by fitting a linear function or 1/x or something similar onto the rising edge?
Hence, by plotting the diode curve double-logarithmically you can see an inflection point. Does this maybe describe the breakdown?

[image: log]
[image: Curve]

Comment: Related question by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/358488/2451

Comment: I personally prefer Sze's Physics of Semiconductor Devices (second edition). This is covered in chapter 2, where the avalanche breakdown voltage is defined as the limit where the multiplication factor approaches infinity. Of course, for actual use, you want the voltage lower or else any random carrier will cause avalanche.

Comment: Thanks. Coincidentally this is the one book I already have :) But thanks for the page itself. Are there any further books? The Sze is not easy to read in my opinion. Lots of equations and more or less hard to apply and obviously all the information is hidden in short lines :)